# peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg Error: failed to send transaction: got unexpected status: NOT_FOUND -- channel does not exist

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When I was conducting chain code approval, I encountered the following problem: Error: failed to send transaction: got unexpected status: NOT_FOUND -- Channel does not exist.I have successfully executed the operation of chain code packaging and chain code installation, but I cannot continue when executing the chain code approval. Have you encountered any such problems?  thank you

Here is the information for the current node:

> bash-5.0# peer channel list
> 2020-09-21 10:18:18.939 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
> Channels peers has joined:
> example-channel

> bash-5.0# peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled
> Installed chaincodes on peer:
> Package ID: mycc_1:2499940fe909cc71a661bf79a3d78523a43c4d2879f4456e6cbe4a2a5a5e5246, Label: mycc_1

========================2020-09-22===================
this is my configtx.yaml

```
Organizations:
    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

    - &Org1
        Name: Org1MSP
        ID: Org1MSP
        MSPDir: ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051
    - &Org2
        Name: Org2MSP
        ID: Org2MSP
        MSPDir: ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 7051

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V2_0: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    Addresses: # orderer
        - orderer.example.com:7050
        - orderer2.example.com:7050
        - orderer3.example.com:7050
        - orderer4.example.com:7050
        - orderer5.example.com:7050
    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:

    TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

    SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            EtcdRaft:
                Consenters:
                - Host: orderer.example.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer2.example.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer3.example.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer4.example.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer5.example.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.crt
            Addresses:
                - orderer.example.com:7050
                - orderer2.example.com:7050
                - orderer3.example.com:7050
                - orderer4.example.com:7050
                - orderer5.example.com:7050

            Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
            - <<: *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
```

---

this is my host list:

```
|order.example.com|182.23.20.1|order|
 |peer0.org1.example.com|182.23.20.2|org1|
 |peer1.org1.example.com|182.23.20.3|org1|
 |peer0.org2.example.com|182.23.20.4|org2|
 |peer1.org2.example.com|182.23.20.5|org2|
```

So here's how I do it
Step one:Generate certificate file

```
cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
```

Step two:Create system channels

```
configtxgen -profile SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft -outputBlock ../channel-artifacts/orderer.genesis.block -channelID system-channel
```

Step three:Create application channels

```
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ../channel-artifacts/example-channel.tx -channelID example-channel
```

Step four:Anchor node update

```
configtxgen  -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ../channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID example-channel -asOrg Org1MSP
    configtxgen  -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ../channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID example-channel -asOrg Org2MSP
```

Step five:Create channels on nodes ,on peer0.org1 nodes

```
 peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c example-channel  \
    -f ./channel-artifacts/example-channel.tx --tls  --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
```

Step six : join channel and Anchor node update

```
peer channel join -b example-channel.block
#Anchor node update
peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c example-channel -f ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

This is true of other peer nodes
Step seven:chaincode manager,use fabcar

```
# 1:gradlew installDist
cd ~/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/example/chaincode/fabcar/java 
    ./gradlew installDist
#2:chaincode package
 peer lifecycle chaincode package mycc.tar.gz \
    --path /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode/fabcar/java/build/install/fabcar \
    --lang java --label mycc_1
#3:chaincode install
peer lifecycle chaincode install mycc.tar.gz
```

This is true for all other nodes
I tried using 'peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled'the command to execute on each peer and got the following results:

```
Installed chaincodes on peer:
    Package ID: mycc_1:2499940fe909cc71a661bf79a3d78523a43c4d2879f4456e6cbe4a2a5a5e5246, Label: mycc_1
```

#4:chaincode approveformyorg

```
 export CC_PACKAGE_ID=mycc_1:2499940fe909cc71a661bf79a3d78523a43c4d2879f4456e6cbe4a2a5a5e5246
    # cafile path
 export CF=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
    # cc_name
export CC_NAME=example-channel
peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg -o orderer.example.com:7050 \
     --channelID $CC_NAME --name mycc --version 1.0 --package-id $CC_PACKAGE_ID --sequence 1 --tls \
     --cafile $CF  --signature-policy "OR('Org1MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.peer')"
```

When I executed the command, there was an error:

```
Error: failed to send transaction: got unexpected status: NOT_FOUND -- channel does not exist
```

Finally, there are no error messages in any of the above procedures below the supplement!

Do you have a good solution,think you !!!

Comment: Hi @Jiang Long Wei. Could you share the command that you execute? Also, it would be great if you share you configtx.yaml file content

Comment: I've added configtx.yaml and Process of execution ,It's up there!  3Q

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you follow all the steps to create the channel properly.

Those steps are:

1. create the channel transaction artifact using configtxgen
2. create the channel on network using "peer channel create" command
3. join the peer on that channel using "peer channel join"

Now when you will give the approval, make sure you use "--channelID" flag in approval time.

Comment: I checked these procedures, but found no problem!

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be an error caused by your Orderer Service. Although you define at your configuration file `configtx.yaml` that you will have 5 orderer nodes, in your logs you only show one: `|order.example.com|182.23.20.1|order|`. So, it seems that you are not startintg up all those 5 orderers. Have you checked your `order.example.com` logs?

However, you could try one (or both) of the following changes?

1. I think that you should try removing the configuration of the rest of the orderers from your configuration files, i.e. you only should have defined the `orderer.example.com`. Then, you should execute all the steps again. Remember removing the docker containers and volumes created previously.
2. The second test could be replicating the configuration of the `orderer.example.com`. You would try to recplicate the definition of the `orderer.example.com`. Because it seems that you are not defining and starting up the rest of the orderers that you should have running.